# Sidr missing file

Tags: sidr

I installed sidr with bower, but when I try to run gulp, it breaks and outputs the following error

```
bower_components/sidr/src/scss/sidr/_base.scss
Error: File to import not found or unreadable: compass/css3
        on line 1 of bower_components/sidr/src/scss/sidr/_base.scss
>> @import 'compass/css3';
   ^
```

I looked, and this `compass/css3` file does not exists. `_base.scss` is the only file in that directory. Is there a fix for this that won't get over written whenever bower updates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you're using it with, but I'm trying to get it working with WordPress/Sage and found [this link](https://discourse.roots.io/t/adding-compass-to-gulpfile-js/3210/3).

*Basically*:

1. Run `npm install compass-mixins --save-dev` in your theme directory. **(See Edit 1 Below)**
2. Edit the `cssTasks` - `includePaths` section of your `gulpfile.js` to point to the location of the compass folder eg: `'./node_modules/compass-mixins/lib'`

Hope that helps!

---

### **Caveat**

While that fixed the error for not finding the compass/css3 folder, I am now getting these warnings:

```
WARNING: PIE does not support background-image. Use @include background(linear-gradient(#4d4d4d, #1a1a1a)) instead.
    on line 74 of node_modules/compass-mixins/lib/compass/css3/_images.scss
    from line 46 of bower_components/sidr/src/scss/sidr/_base.scss

WARNING: PIE does not support background-image. Use @include background(linear-gradient(white, #dfdfdf)) instead.
    on line 74 of node_modules/compass-mixins/lib/compass/css3/_images.scss
    from line 46 of bower_components/sidr/src/scss/sidr/_base.scss
```

---

It also seems to be causing issues with uglify-js because I could run `gulp` fine before bower installing sidr.

Will update as I progress.

### **EDIT 1**

After reading [this](https://github.com/Igosuki/compass-mixins/issues/68), I uninstalled the `npm compass-mixins` package and installed via `bower` and changed the path in the `gulpfile.js` accordingly.

The Warnings for PIE are gone. Still experiencing issues with `uglify-js` though.

---

### **EDIT 2**

Ran `npm install gulp-util` and set up the gulpfile to output more info on the error.

```
{ [Error: scripts/main.js: Unexpected token: name (sidr)]
      message: 'scripts/main.js: Unexpected token: name (sidr)',
      fileName: 'scripts/main.js',
      ...
      showStack: false,
      showProperties: true,
      plugin: 'gulp-uglify' }
```

---

Comment: Thanks! Didn't realize I had to install compass separately.